# Migration asp.net web api to asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, migration

My asp.net static constructor which was getting called when sending mail

```
static EmailHelper()
        {
            //load configuration from config file

            int intSmtpPort = 0;
            int.TryParse(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpport"], out intSmtpPort);
            host = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpclient"];
            port = intSmtpPort;
            user = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"];
            password = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
            fromEmail = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["frommail"];

        }
```

My asp.net core static constructor class which throws error as it should be parameterless but i need to use the configuration

```
 static EmailHelper(IOptions<SmtpConfig> smtpConfig)
        {
            int intSmtpPort = 0;
            int.TryParse(SmtpConfig.smtpport, out intSmtpPort);
            host = SmtpConfig.smtpclient;
            port = intSmtpPort;
            user = SmtpConfig.username;
            password = SmtpConfig.password;
            fromEmail = SmtpConfig.frommail;

        }
```

If i use a public constructor its not getting called. What should i do? Is there another way to inject configuration settings in my class without using dependency injection?

Comment: Can you make the class an instance type instead of a static class?

Answer (score 1):

A static constructor cannot be used for dependency injection.

Why don't you make a non-static constructor and register the EmailHelper as a service in the dependency injection?

This way you can inject and use the EmailHelper anywhere you need it.